# How to implement calculating pAUC and its derivatives in python?

Tags: python, xgboost, lightgbm, catboost

According to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.04838.pdf), the method of maximizing pAUC is useful for unbalanced binary classification problems.
Since gradient boosting libraries such as LightGBM, CatBoost and XGBoost do not implement pAUC, if you want to use pAUC as a loss function in these libraries, you will need to implement it on your own, along with the first and second derivatives.
I have implemented the code to calculate pAUC but cannot determine if this is correct. Also, I do not know how to implement its derivatives.
Do you have any ideas?

Assuming pandas DataFrame df has two columns named 'target' and 'pred_proba'.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class p_auc:
    def __init__(self, alpha=0.01, beta=0.1):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
    
    def calculate_p_auc(self, df, target_label='target', proba_label='pred_proba'):
        S_pos = df[df[target_label] == 1]
        S_neg = df[df[target_label] == 0].sort_values(proba_label, ascending=False)

        x_pos = np.array(S_pos.iloc[:,1])
        x_neg = np.array(S_neg.iloc[:,1])
        n_pos = len(x_pos)
        n_neg = len(x_neg)
        j_alpha = math.ceil(self.alpha * n_neg)
        j_beta = math.floor(self.beta * n_neg)

        res = 0
        for i in range(n_pos):
            res += (j_alpha - self.alpha * n_neg) * self.sigmoid(x_pos[i], x_neg[j_alpha - 1])
            for j in range(j_alpha, j_beta):
                res += self.sigmoid(x_pos[i], x_neg[j])
            res += (self.beta * n_neg - j_beta) * self.sigmoid(x_pos[i], x_neg[j_beta])
        res /= n_pos * n_neg * (self.beta - self.alpha)
        
        return res
    
    def sigmoid(self, a, b):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-1 * (a - b)))
```

Comment: Sadly, I am not able to confirm your set up, however I would like to ask a question in regards to it. Assuming it is designed correctly, how would you implement in in a model.fit() method? would you just make eval_metric=p_auc when calling the fit method?